# console.log(self) has output field but console.log(self.output) is undefined

Tags: typescript

I am having this strange issue. When I `console.log(self`) variable it has the output key set and has all the values in it. But if I try to `console.log(self.output)` it gives me undefined does anyone know why is it happening?

Here is my code:

```
interface SearchOutput {
    total: 0,
    per_page: number,
    current_page: number,
    last_page: number,
    from: number,
    to: number,
    data: Array<Object>
}

interface SearchParams {
    query: string,
    perPage: number,
    index: string,
    type: string,
    page: number
}

export class Elastic {
    from: number;
    to: number;
    client: any;
    output: SearchOutput;
    error: any;

    constructor(host: string, log: string, elasticsearch: any) {
        this.client = new elasticsearch.Client({
            host: host,
            log: log
        })
    }

    public search({query, perPage, index, type, page}:SearchParams): SearchOutput {
        let self = this;
        this.client.search({
                'index': index,
                'type': type,
                'body': {
                    'query': {
                        'bool': {
                            'must': {
                                'query_string': {
                                    'query': query,
                                    'default_operator': 'AND',
                                    'fuzziness': 1
                                }
                            }, 'filter': []
                        }
                    }
                },
                'size': perPage,
                'from': 0
            },
            (err, response) => {
                const {hits, hits: {total}} = response
                const lastPage = Math.ceil(total / perPage)
                const from = (page * perPage) - perPage + 1
                const to = (page < lastPage) ? page * perPage : total
                let output = {
                    total: total,
                    per_page: perPage,
                    current_page: page,
                    last_page: lastPage,
                    from: from,
                    to: to,
                    data: []
                }
                if (total >= 1) {
                    for (const key in hits.hits) {
                        if (hits.hits.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            output.data.push(hits.hits[key]._source);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    output.data = [];
                }
                self.output = output;
            }
        );
        console.log(self); // outputs Elastic {client: EsApiClient, output:SearchOutput Objest with all values}
        console.log(self.output) // outputs undefined
        return self.output;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a race condition where you are console.logging possibly before the callback is executed. It looks like you are setting initial values for self.output, but are you sure they are the values you expect?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I am struggling to return results from a callback into a method and have no idea how to go around it.

Comment: Since the data you want your method to return is coming back asynchronously, you will need to do something such as add a callback parameter to your search method. I will edit my answer and add an example of how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `console.log` into the callback like so:

```
    this.client.search({
            'index': index,
            'type': type,
            'body': {
                'query': {
                    'bool': {
                        'must': {
                            'query_string': {
                                'query': query,
                                'default_operator': 'AND',
                                'fuzziness': 1
                            }
                        }, 'filter': []
                    }
                }
            },
            'size': perPage,
            'from': 0
        },
        (err, response) => {
            const {hits, hits: {total}} = response
            const lastPage = Math.ceil(total / perPage)
            const from = (page * perPage) - perPage + 1
            const to = (page < lastPage) ? page * perPage : total
            let output = {
                total: total,
                per_page: perPage,
                current_page: page,
                last_page: lastPage,
                from: from,
                to: to,
                data: []
            }
            if (total >= 1) {
                for (const key in hits.hits) {
                    if (hits.hits.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        output.data.push(hits.hits[key]._source);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                output.data = [];
            }
            self.output = output;
            console.log(self.output);
        }
    );
```

EDIT: this is one way of handling the async data coming back and returning it.

Your current search method signature: `public search({query, perPage, index, type, page}:SearchParams): SearchOutput`

Update it to `public search({query, perPage, index, type, page}:SearchParams, callback): SearchOutput`

Now when you get the data back (in the callback within this method) you can call the callback that is passed in:

```
if (total >= 1) {
    for (const key in hits.hits) {
        if (hits.hits.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            output.data.push(hits.hits[key]._source);
        }
    }
} else {
    output.data = [];
}
    callback(output) // calls callback method passed in with the returned value
```

Now you can call search like this:

```
search(
    {'somequery', 'someperPage', 'someindex', 'sometype', 'somepage'}, 
    (data) => console.log(data)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you time and help.